# RequestAnimationFrame in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I want to animate a segment of a circle (45 degrees) in a canvas. But for some reasons it won't work. What am I making wrong here?

[**[Demo][1]**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhgL693o/1/)

```
window.onload = function() {
            (function() {
              var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
              window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
            })();
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var startAngle = Math.PI * 1.5;
            var endAngle   = startAngle + 45 * (Math.PI / 180);
            var percent = 0;
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#ad2323';
            function animate (cur){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, startAngle, endAngle * cur, false);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                percent++;
                requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                     animate(percent / 100)
                });
            }
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling `animate` from the first time? Also, you probably want to bail out when percent reaches 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of bugs in your code. The problem is not related to `requestAnimationFrame`.

1. You need `endAngle` to be a delta you want to animate i.e. 45 deg. You are using linear function for animation which is `start + (end - start)*cur` not `end*cur`.
2. You don't have radius specified.
3. You need to check for `percent` to be less than 100.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/jhgL693o/3/).

Comment: Thanks, I have really lost focus after a long time trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, startAngle, endAngle * percent, false);
```

Not sure if you are using the arguments of `requestAnimationFrame()` properly.